# Calculate the starting and ending date/time from a given year and week number

Tags: c++, datetime

How do I calculate the starting and ending date/time (YYYY-mm-DD HH:MM::SS) for a given year and ISO week number of the year?

I searched SO before asking this kind of question again. Surely, there were some threads concerning to the conversion from (year, weeknumber) to (datetime) on SO. But they were answered by speaking Perl, PHP, JAVA, SQL, C#, .NET, Excel, and and other programming languages except the C/C++.

Comment: SO is not the place for getting verbatim solutions to programming tasks.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid there is no short solution to this problem using simple C++. However it shouldn't be a tough job writing the solution. You just need to take care of exceptional cases (like the first and last week, february, leap year). An approach can be

1. From the week number for a year, get the `day numbers` (ie, start and end day number) for that year. (take care of the first and last week here)
2. Now it is simple to find the month and date in with the `day numbers` lie. (take care of february here)

Comment: Thank you for your kind suggestion! I'll try to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You could start with code below and adjust it a bit (what is your definition of first week: first full week or first partial week). Also you have to handle special cases of first and last week.

```
  int const year = 2012;
  int const week = 24;
  boost::gregorian::greg_weekday const firstDayOfWeek = boost::gregorian::Monday;

  boost::gregorian::date const jan1st(year, boost::gregorian::Jan, 1);
  boost::gregorian::first_day_of_the_week_after const firstDay2ndWeek(firstDayOfWeek);
  boost::gregorian::date const begin2ndWeek = firstDay2ndWeek.get_date(jan1st);
  boost::gregorian::date const end2ndWeek = begin2ndWeek + boost::gregorian::days(6);

  boost::gregorian::date const beginNthWeek = begin2ndWeek + boost::gregorian::weeks(week - 2);
  boost::gregorian::date const endNthWeek = end2ndWeek + boost::gregorian::weeks(week - 2);

  std::cout << boost::gregorian::to_iso_extended_string(jan1st) << std::endl;
  std::cout << boost::gregorian::to_iso_extended_string(begin2ndWeek) << std::endl;
  std::cout << boost::gregorian::to_iso_extended_string(end2ndWeek) << std::endl;
  std::cout << boost::gregorian::to_iso_extended_string(beginNthWeek) << std::endl;
  std::cout << boost::gregorian::to_iso_extended_string(endNthWeek) << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to help other people, I want to answer my own question as follows:

```
COleDateTime YearWeekDayToCalendarDate(int nYear, int nWeekNumber, int nWeekDay)
{   
// This method requires that one know the weekday of 4 January of the year in question
int nFirstWeekDay = WeekDay(nYear, 1, 4);

// Add 3 to the number of this weekday, giving a correction to be used for dates within this year
int nDaysOffset = nFirstWeekDay + 3;

// Multiply the week number by 7, then add the weekday. 
int nOrdinalDayNumber = (nWeekNumber * 7) + nWeekDay;

// From this sum subtract the correction for the year.
nOrdinalDayNumber = nOrdinalDayNumber - nDaysOffset;

// If the ordinal date thus obtained is zero or negative, the date belongs to the previous calendar year; 
if (nOrdinalDayNumber <= 0)
   nYear--;

int nTotalDaysInTheYear = 365;

if ( LeapYear(nYear) )
   nTotalDaysInTheYear++;

// If greater than the number of days in the year, to the following year.
if (nOrdinalDayNumber > nTotalDaysInTheYear)
   nYear++;

// The result is the ordinal date, which can be converted into a calendar date using the following function
unsigned int nMonth, nDay;
YearDayToMonthDay(nOrdinalDayNumber, nYear, nDay, nMonth);

COleDateTime dtCalendar(nYear, nMonth, nDay, 0, 0, 0);

return dtCalendar;
}

int WeekDay(int nYear, int nMonth, int nDay)
{   
// Find the DayOfYearNumber for the specified nYear, nMonth, and nDay
const int AccumulateDaysToMonth [] = {0, 31, 59, 90, 120, 151, 181, 212, 243, 273, 304, 334};

// Set DayofYear Number for nYear, nMonth, and nDay
int nDayOfYearNumber = nDay + AccumulateDaysToMonth[nMonth - 1];

// Increase of Dayof Year Number by 1, if year is leapyear and month greater than February
//if ( LeapYear(nYear) && (nMonth == 2) )
if ( LeapYear(nYear) && (nMonth > 2) )
   nDayOfYearNumber += 1;

// Find the Jan1Weekday for nYear (Monday = 1, Sunday = 7)
int i, j, k, l, nJan1Weekday, nWeekday;

i = (nYear - 1) % 100;
j = (nYear - 1) - i;
k = i + i / 4;

nJan1Weekday = 1 + (((((j / 100) % 4) * 5) + k) % 7);

// Calcuate the WeekDay for the given date
l = nDayOfYearNumber + (nJan1Weekday - 1);
nWeekday = 1 + ((l - 1) % 7);

return nWeekday;
}

void YearDayToMonthDay(unsigned int nYearDay, unsigned int nYear, 
                       unsigned int& nMonthDay, unsigned int& nMonth)
{   
// Day is the day between 1 and 366
// Year is the year you wish
unsigned int nMonthTable[12] = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
unsigned int nMonthDays = 0;

if ((nYear % 4 == 0) && ((!(nYear % 100 == 0)) || (nYear % 400 == 0))) 
   nMonthTable[1] = 29;
else 
   nMonthTable[1] = 28;

nMonth = 0;

while (nYearDay > nMonthDays) 
   nMonthDays += nMonthTable[nMonth++];

nMonthDay = nYearDay - nMonthDays + nMonthTable[nMonth - 1];
}

inline bool LeapYear( int nYear )  
{  
// Find if nYear is LeapYear        
if ( (nYear % 4 == 0 && nYear % 100 != 0) || nYear % 400 == 0)
  return true;
else
  return false;
}
```